# Machine Learning library in Java

Tags: library, java, api, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm new to Machine learning, and am trying to learn to develop some deep neural networks applications, possibly for both data analysis and multimedia/image processing. I'm a Java person myself so I would like a library so that I can code in Java.

One example task can be to identify if a given video is a commercial ad or not. I have a big set of ad videos and non ads (movies and sports).

Important factors are performance, support and popularity, coverages of problems, and ease of use.

What library would you recommend me, based on that?

Comment: There are unfortunately not a lot of good Java ML libraries around. TensorFlow has a Java API, but it's worse than the C++ API (which is worse than the Python API). There's DeepLearning4J, but it's also (in my experience) limited

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm from the deeplearning4j project. We have a new pytorch like api about done alongside Tensorflow model import. We already support keras import. Replying to the above commenter a bit: I"m not sure what you find "limiting" per se considering it serves most users fine (especially CNN frameworks and the like) - people calling dl4j limited usually don't actually spend more than 5 minutes looking at it. Anyways, come over to our gitter if you have any questions: https://gitter.im/deeplearnig4j/deeplearning4j